# File import not working correctly in some devices in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I am trying to import ".txt" file and read its data but facing some issue that it does not read the file in some devices (including bluestack and tablets with android 9 on it). It does not give any error or exception. I am sharing the code after spending more than 3 weeks trying to figure out the root cause and finding its solution.. Any help will be highly appreciated. thanks.

`

```
private void readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.i("", line + "\n");

            String line1 = line;
            String lineForCheck = line1.replaceAll(" ","");
            String lineWithoutSlasht = lineForCheck.replaceAll("\t","");

            if (lineWithoutSlasht.equalsIgnoreCase("MD(ft)Inclination(?)Azimuth(?)")) {
                // call method to extract data from file type 1
                isReadyToFill = false;
                extractDataFromFileTypeOne(uri);
                return;
            } else if (lineWithoutSlasht.equalsIgnoreCase("MDInclinAzimuth")) {
                extractDataFromFileTypeTwo(uri);
                // call method to extract data from file type 2
                return;
            } else if (lineWithoutSlasht.equalsIgnoreCase("MeasuredInclDriftTrueVerticalCLOSURECLOSUREDogleg")) {
                // call method to extract data from file type 3
                extractDataFromFileTypeThree(uri);
                return;

            }
        }




public void extractDataFromFileTypeOne(Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int count = 0;
        String line;
        String characterAtThisPosition;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                inputStream));

        boolean setdata = false;
        try {

            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uri));

            Log.i("", "open text file - content" + "\n");
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String line1 = line;
                String lineForCheck = line1.replaceAll(" ","");
                String lineWithoutSlasht = lineForCheck.replaceAll("\t","");

                if (lineWithoutSlasht.equalsIgnoreCase("MD(ft)Inclination(?)Azimuth(?)")) {

                    isReadyToFill = true;
                    line = reader.readLine();

                }

                if (isReadyToFill) {
                    line = line.trim();

                    if (!line.equals("")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                            characterAtThisPosition = Character.toString(line.charAt(i));

                            if ((!characterAtThisPosition.equals("\t")) && !characterAtThisPosition.equals(" ")) {
                                stringBuffer.append(line.charAt(i));
                            } else {
                                if (!(stringBuffer.length() == 0)) {
                                    count++;
                                    setdata = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (setdata) {

                                switch (count) {

                                    case 1:
                                        arrMDImport.add(Double.valueOf(stringBuffer.toString()));
                                        stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.capacity() - 1);
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        arrInclinationImport.add(Double.valueOf(stringBuffer.toString()));
                                        stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.capacity() - 1);
                                        break;
                                }

                                setdata = false;
                            }
                        }
                        arrAzimuthImport.add(Double.valueOf(stringBuffer.toString()));
                        stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.capacity() - 1);
                        count = 0;
                    }


                }
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: have you tried running this on an android9 tablet and checking the logs there ?

Comment: yes already tried that many time, as it is not giving any exception could not figure out what is wrong with it.